# Angular2 : how to prevent exception on specific file like zone.js?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, angular, visual-studio-code

I develop and debug an Angular 2 Application with Visual Studio Code, attached to Chrome (v 48) for the debug.

Each time I launch the Application I have an exception on the line:

```
fetchPromise = global['fetch']();
```

**Is there a trick to avoid stopping the debugger on that exception each time I launch my Application with the debugger ?**

Here is the code in zone.js where I have the exception:

```
if (NativePromise) {
    patchThen(NativePromise);
    if (typeof global['fetch'] !== 'undefined') {
        var fetchPromise = void 0;
        try {
            // In MS Edge this throws
            fetchPromise = global['fetch']();   // <== Exception HERE 
        }
        catch (e) {
            // In Chrome this throws instead.
            fetchPromise = global['fetch']('about:blank');
        }
```

I used zone.js v0.6.26 in the package.json, I updated to 0.7.2 and the exception is still there.

Comment: Mentioned this [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/256) for now, will let you know of any update.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to the suggestion posted [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/256) by roblouren and linked by LEOTM. Adding the file `zone.js` to the `expertimentalSkipDiles` option of the `launch.json` is a perfect solution for that irritating exception.

The exception is still there but it won't pop up at the screen each time the code is compiled and updated.

In the Visual Studio Code project's **launch.json**:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [{
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost:3000",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "experimentalSkipFiles": [
                "zone.js"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `"skipFiles":["vendor.bundle.js"]` in your launch.json configuration will fix it for you